# Sumif in excel rows

Tags: excel

I want to create a formula in excel that will sum total hours.  Here is how the sheet will look.

row 1 2, 5, 7,1, 4, 5
row 2 X,  , X,,   , X  Total Hours

row 3 X,  , X,X,   , X  Total Hours
etc.

row one indicate number of hours.

in the total hours cell I want to add the number of hours (row 1) where the cells in row n are not blank ?

Here is what I tried but it return 0.
=SUMIF(E1:I1,NOT="",E2:I2)

Comment: Hey I found out how to do it.  the correct formula is =SUMIF(E2:I2,"<>",E1:I1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I found out how to do it. the correct formula is =SUMIF(E2:I2,"<>",E1:I1)